# Does a set being nonempty imply that it always has more than one element?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I was looking at the proof for the theorem "*If a nonempty set S has an upper bound, then S has a least upper bound L."* This is the first few lines of the proof:

> Since $S \neq \emptyset $, there exists $s \in S$. Select any number
>   $a_1 \lt s$ so that $a_1$ is too small to be an upper bound for S.

I understand that $S$ contains some element $s$ but how do we know there is also an element $a_1$? What if the set was a set with just one element, namely $s$? As the proof goes on further, it seems like there are actually infinitely many elements in the set $S$.

Comment: I am guessing all this happens in the real line $\;\Bbb R\;$ and thus $\;a_1\in\Bbb R\;$ , *not necessarily* in $\;S\;$ .

Comment: So the element $a_1$ could or could not be in $S$? But then, how does the proof works? Shouldn't $a_1 \in S$ because we are trying to prove the set $S$ has a least upper bound, not $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: You're aware of the fact that you have **not** included any proof, right? The fact the reals fulfill this conditions is very well known and basic, though, so the proof is likely to be a standard one.

Comment: Note that a least upper bound of a set need not be contained in the set itself.

Comment: Look at your title: "non empty" is equivalent to "at least one element..." not "more than one element".

Comment: @LeBtz I just realized that definition of the least upper bound does not state that it must be in the same set that it bounds. This makes it so much clearer...

Comment: @JeanMarie Also, if the set only has one element, say $S = \{s\} $, $s$ is the least upper bound so the proof is trivial, am I right?

Comment: Maybe I should have a better look at your question... like @LeBtz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is obvious that if $\max S$ exists then $\max S =\sup S.$ So to prove that any non-empty $S$ with an upper bound has a $\sup,$ it suffices to prove it for the case of a non-empty $S$ with no largest member. And a non-empty set of numbers with no largest member must be an infinite set.

There is a variety of ways to define $\mathbb R,$ but they all produce the same structure. Proving that any non-empty subset of $\mathbb R$ with an upper bound has a $\sup$ may depend on which def'n of $\mathbb R$ you choose ( unless  you first prove its equivalence to another def'n.)